# .profile ran into an infinite loop

Tags: 10.04, .profile

I changed my .profile to run a script at startup. That scripts loops through all the files in a folder and sets it as the background image. It sleeps for 10 seconds before it sets the next one as the wallpaper. The problem is, I didn't tell it to run as a background process.

So, at login, it runs the script in the main thread and I'm screwed. I can't do anything. It's not responsive. I have nearly 1200 images, so it could take nearly 3.33 hours to complete. I can wait but I don't want to. Is there any solution?

BTW, the login screen does not appear at login. It automatically signs in (I checked that option at Ubuntu install). So, there's no apparent way to log in using Failsafe Gnome mode.

I use Ubuntu 10.04. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, and it is one of the feature of Linux: you can get to a console by pressing <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd>

Use `cd` to go to the directory where you edited the file and restore the backup profile you created before you editted it ( ;) ) or just edit the file if you did not make a backup.

```
nano .profile
```

When you're done, <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> to save and exit and then just run `sudo restart lightdm` to restart the graphical server. If that didn't work, back to TTY1 and edit your `.profile` again.

Alternatively you can so the same using the live CD: boot from it and mount the disc that has your .profile and edit it.

Comment: I booted into recovery mode and changed the .profile. This would have been a better way, but I read this after I got it working. Thank you.

Comment: no problem! glad you got it fixed. and thanks Oli.