# How to skip StartUp and/or .profile on log-in?

Tags: login, startup-applications, .profile

Is there a login option to skip processing the .profile and Startup Applications? I basically have a script in there that's hanging the system upon log-in. The filesystem is encrypted and I don't have the passphrase and there are no other root users. So I'd like to login in as the user but without processing the script in .profile or Startup Applications.

Comment: You could use the root shell provided by recovery mode entry in the Grub menu.

Answer (score 1):

You were asking for direct and quick access to root user. Try recovery mode option in grub. It perfectly fine for you.

In recovery mode open, prompt-shell

It will looks like text-user-interface like terminal

Answer (score 0):

Just stumbled onto a great solution for me, as described in "[.profile ran into an infinite loop](https://askubuntu.com/q/104721/309677)."

**Log in from a console (Control-Alt-F1) and ^C the script.** 
Evidently the script was only hanging the GUI, not the system. So technically this didn't avoid running the script, but it let me stop it and remove it from the .profile to restore the GUI login functionality. 
Thanks AskUbuntu!